# Two TRRS cables: both work great in macOS but only one works in Windows?

Tags: macos, windows-10, cable, microphone, headphone-jack

I have two four-contact (TRRS) headphone cables that I'm trying to use with a 2013 15" Macbook Pro: a Monoy Replacement Beats Audio Cable and a V-MODA 1-Button Speakeasy Cable. In macOS, both cables work fine. The microphone shows up as an input device and the button controls playback. But in Windows 10 (via Bootcamp), only the cheap Monoy cable seems to work correctly. When the V-MODA cable is plugged in, the microphone doesn't show up as an input device. It can only be used as a straight audio cable.

What could possibly account for this difference in behavior? Is there any way to make the V-MODA cable work like the Monoy cable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got a replacement cable and this one works fine on both platforms. So the answer is: faulty cable. No idea what kind of fault would cause this specific problem, though!